# how to capitalize first letter after "."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote this function for it :

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');

const capitalizeClick =()=>{
        var str = text.split(".") ;
        let newText = str.map((arr)=>(arr[0].toUpperCase()));
        setText(newText)

        
    }
     return(
       <textarea className="form-control" value={text} onChange={handleOnChange}  id="myBox" rows={15}  />
             
    )
```

but i am geting this error :
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')

Comment: Please add sample input data along with the output you expect?

Comment: Tip: It's 2022. Embrace `let` and forget about `var`. You seem to be on the fence here.

Comment: You can actually just use css,` <p style={{ textTransform: 'capitalise' }}>`

Comment: Tip: `(x).y` is just `x.y`. Not sure why you have `(arr[0]).toUpperCase`. Maybe you mean `arr[0].toUpperCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept text as an argument to the function.

```
const capitalizeClick = (text)=> {
        var str = text.split(".") ;
        let newText = str.map((arr)=>((arr[0]).toUpperCase));
        setText(newText)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with a simple regex. This will capitalize all first letters after each `.`

```
const capitalizeText = text => text?.replace(/\.(.)/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase())
capitalizeText("This.is.a.test")
```

> This.Is.A.Test

To modify it to do only once, just remove the global modifier.

```
const capitalizeText = text => text?.replace(/\.(.)/, letter => letter.toUpperCase())
capitalizeText("This.is.a.test")
```

> This.Is.a.test

Comment: It's showing this error : text.replace is not a function
    at capitalizeClick

Comment: @Geetika Hmm.. It's running in the browser. https://ibb.co/02VZY3m Are you sure text is supplied as a string and not null? I've updated the answer wih a nullsafe operator. Can you check again?

Answer (score 0):

Using split, map and join probably

```js
const capitalize = (text) => {
  return text
    .split(".")
    .map((w, i) => {
      if (i !== 0) {
        w = w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1);
      }
      return w;
    })
    .join(".");
};

console.log(capitalize("hello.world"));
console.log(capitalize("hello.world.rowdy"));
console.log(capitalize("hello"));
console.log(capitalize(".hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
red = input("hi ")
singers = red.split('. ')

singers = [singer.capitalize() for singer in singers]
joined = ". ".join(singers)
print(joined)
```

This is in python it shouldn't be to hard to change it to JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

The function in your question needs a few corrections. For one, it only capitalizes the first letter and returns that character alone, leaving the rest of the characters present in the word. But.....

That's not the cause of the error you're getting. Without a way to check your full code, my assumption is that the function is being called when the `text` is actually empty (the initial value), and that makes the value of `arr[0]` to be `undefined` (since there is no character at index `0`). Make sure that `text` has a valid string, and that there is at least one character before and after each `.`